# PDO ORDER BY COUNT

Tags: php, pdo

I need a PDO query to get top 20 most searched for terms (returning the search-term and the number of times it was used).

This SQL does exactly what I want (tested in PhpMyAdmin) . . .

```
SELECT searchterm, COUNT(*) AS rowcount 
FROM table 
GROUP BY searchterm 
ORDER BY rowcount DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

. . . but PDO always returns rowcount as 1.

I 've read loads of related posts, but can't seem to adapt those solutions to this problem (probably because I don't understand PDO well enough).

Didn't want to post my PDO code as I'm using a wrapper I've built (that mostly works great) and think I need to start from scratch with this problem . . . but here it is (sanitised from wrapper) . . .

```
$query = $this -> db -> prepare (
SELECT searchterm, COUNT(*) AS rowcount 
FROM table 
GROUP BY searchterm 
ORDER BY rowcount DESC 
LIMIT 20);
$query -> execute (); 
$return = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: we can not guess what is your PDO code

Comment: Ofc there is a PDO here and is the one you using, show us your PDO code you using to query the sql's query u have.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give me your output of this ? and I'll edit the answer.
You could easily use PDO to group by the first column:

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `searchterm`, COUNT(*) AS `rowcount` FROM `table` ORDER BY rowcount DESC LIMIT 20");
$query->execute();
$return = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

Just show me your `var_dump($return)`

Comment: array(2) { [""]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } ["newbury"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } }

Comment: so first array is no (empty) search term with 4 rows and second array is 'newbury' search term with 2 rows - which is correct data from db

Comment: Thanks Ido - starting to see light at end of tunnel - but this does not order the results by 'rowcount' - happens to be in correct order in above var_dump - but just tested with more data and its not ordering results at all